# Passing rvalue references vs non-const lvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

If I have no use for a variable after I pass it to a function, does it matter whether I pass it a non-const lvalue reference or use std::move to pass it an rvalue reference. The assumption is that there are two different overloads. The only difference in the two cases is the lifetime of the passed object, which ends earlier if I pass by rvalue reference. Are there other factors to consider?

If I have a function foo overloaded like:

```
void foo(X& x);
void foo(X&& x);

X x;
foo(std::move(x));   // Does it matter if I called foo(x) instead?
// ... no further accesses to x
// end-of-scope
```

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of an object does not end when it is passed by rvalue reference. The rvalue reference merely gives `foo` permission to take ownership of its argument and potentially change its value to nonsense. This might involve deallocating its members, which is a kind of end of lifetime, but the argument itself lives to the end of the scope of its declaration.

Using `std::move` on the last access is idiomatic. There is no potential downside. Presumably if there are two overloads, the rvalue reference one has the same semantics but higher efficiency. Of course, they could do completely different things, just for the sake of insane sadism.

Comment: The lifetime could be shorter, it need not be. If you pass an object by rvalue reference to a function and the function returns, assuming that the object went out of scope in the called function, the object ceases to exist. But if you had passed an lvalue-reference, the object would still be around when the function returned.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee A reference is not an object, and there is no effect to a reference going out of scope. It is merely an idiom that an object's value becomes meaningless after the completion of a function accepting it by rvalue reference. The function has no effect whatsoever on lifetime, and if you wish to use other semantics — even using an rvalue reference to return information the same as an lvalue reference — you are free to do so.

Comment: You are correct. I meant lifetime of the underlying resources. Say my object obj is an instance of class MyString and it has a character buffer inside it. If I pass it by lvalue reference to function process_string(MyString&), then, after the call to process_string returns, the internal buffer would still exist. If I call process_string(MyString&&) using std::move and the call to process_string returns, then unless the passed object obj was moved to some more durable scope inside process_string, the internal buffer would have been deallocated at the time process_string returned.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee Nothing happens automatically at the `return` statement of `process_string`. If `process_string` doesn't call `move` on its parameter, the internal buffer will still be there in the argument object after the function call.

Comment: So basically, if I have an lvalue on which I call move to pass it some function foo:
    void foo(X&& x);
    ...
    X obj;
    foo(std::move(obj));

then this does not mean that obj's content has been moved to some lvalue with scope limited to foo. In this case, the behavior is same
as passing an lvalue reference.

However if, inside the function foo, I have something like this:
    void foo(X&& x) {
      X obj1(std::move(x));
    }
then the obj is moved to obj1. On the other hand, if I did this: foo(X("bar")), then even without a move inside the foo, the object would be deallocated in foo.

Comment: Thanks. The "permission to take ownership of its argument and potentially change its value to nonsense" seems to specifically apply to temporaries. I could do all of this in say void foo(X&) too, but couldn't have called it on temporaries. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee `foo(std::move(obj))` and `X obj1(std::move(x))` *possibly* remove the content from `obj` but idiomatically there is no guarantee. Best practice is to explicitly assign an empty value if you want it to be empty. `foo(X("bar"))` works mostly like `move(obj)` except that `obj` syntactically doesn't have a name. The temporary argument object is still allocated by the caller, although its lifetime ends at the semicolon, whereas `obj` dies at the closing `}` brace.

Comment: As for your second comment-question, yes. There is no difference between assigning junk and assigning a result, but rvalue reference arguments idiomatically get the former and lvalue arguments get the latter, because the language defines rvalues to cover cases where the lifetime is short due to the lack of a name, and lvalues where results can be recovered from a named object.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you do in `foo()`:

- Inside `foo()`, if you store the argument in some internal storage, then yes it does matter, from readability point of view, because it is *explicit* at the call site that this particular argument is being moved and it should not be used here at call site, after the function call returns.
- If you simply read/write its value, then it doesn't matter. Note that even if you pass by `T&`, the argument can still be moved to some internal storage, but that is less preferred approach — in fact it should be considered a dangerous approach.

Also note that `std::move` does NOT actually *move* the object. It simply makes the object *moveable*. An object is moved if it invokes the move-constructor or move-assignment:

```
void f(X && x) { return; }
void g(X x) { return; }

X x1,x2;
f(std::move(x1)); //x1 is NOT actually moved (no move constructor invocation).
g(std::move(x2)); //x2 is actually moved (by the move-constructor).

//here it is safe to use x1
//here it is unsafe to use x2
```

Alright it is more complex than this. Consider another example:

```
void f(X && x) { vec_storage.push_back(std::move(x)); return; }
void g(X x) { return; }

X x1,x2;
f(std::move(x1)); //x1 is actually moved (move-constructor invocation in push_back)
g(std::move(x2)); //x2 is actually moved (move-constructor invocation when passing argument by copy).

//here it is unsafe to use x1 and x2 both.
```

Hope that helps.